# Python regex - exclude a certain match

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to capture the following only:

- .1
- ,2
- '3

The number after .,' can be any digit and can have anything before or after it. So for example, *.1 abc*, I only want to capture the 1 or *abc,2*, I only want to capture the 2.

So if we have the following:

```
10,000
1.1
,1
.2
'3
'100.000
.200,000
'300'000
abc'100,000
abc.4
abc,5
abc'6
abc 7
,8 abc
.9 abc
'10 abc
.11abc
,12abc
```

I have the following python regex:

```
((?<![0-9])([.,':’])([0-9]{1,4}))
```

The problem is that it's capturing '100 in '100.000 and .200 in .200,000 and '300'000 - how can I stop it from capturing this. So it shouldn't capture '100.000 or .200,000 or '300'000 or abc'100,000 and so on.

I use this to test my regex: https://pythex.org/

Why am I doing this? I am converting InDesign files to HTML, and on some of the conversion the footnotes are not working so using RegReplace on SublimeText to find and replace the footnotes with specific HTML.

---

Just want to make it more clear as someone has commented thats not clear.

I want to capture a digit that has a . , ' before it, for example:

> This is a long string with subscript footnote numbers like this.1 Sometimes they have a dot before the footnote number and sometimes they have a comma,2 Then there are times when it has an apostrophe'3 
>   Now the problem with my regex was that it was capturing the numbers after a dot, comma or apostrophe for values like this 30,000 or 20.000 or '10,000. I don't want to capture anything like that except like this'4 or like this.5 or like this ,6

So what I was trying to do with my regex is to look before the dot, comma and apostrophe to see if there was a digit and if there was then I didn't want to capture none of it, e.g. '10,000 or .20.000 or ,15'000

Now mypetlion got the closest but his regex was not capturing the last 3 in the list, let me see what I can with his regex.

Comment: If I'm understanding, you want everything that is a single digit, preceded by one of the given punctuation marks, which is in turn preceded by any non-numeric prefix, and followed by any non-numeric suffix? If that is what you want, try this one: `((?<!\d)([.,':’])(\d)(?!\d))`

Comment: do you want a single digit after .,' or all digits.

Comment: Could you add for each of your input example what output (if any) should be captured? I'm sorry but I find your description quite confusing !

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you don't want to capture '100.000 or .200,000 or '300'000 or abc'100,000 but you do want to capture the rest which contains `[.,']` followed by one or more digits.

You could match them and then use an [alternation](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) `|` and capture in a group what you do want to match:

[`[.,']\d+[.,']\d+|[.,'](\d+)`](https://regex101.com/r/6l7J9R/1)

**Details**

- `[.,']\d+[.,']\d+` Match one of the characters in the character class, one or more digits and match one of the characters in the character class *(the pattern that you don't want to capture)*
- `|` Or
- `[.,'](\d+)` Match one of the characters in the character class and capture in a group one or more digits.

Your values will be in captured group 1

[Demo](http://rextester.com/WXXADW13242)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly and you only want the next digit after ANY comma, period, or single quote then `(([\.,'’])([0-9]))` should do the trick.

If I misunderstand and you have the negative lookbehind for a reason then try this:

`((?<![0-9])([\.,'’])([0-9]))`